# What genre is "Morning Dew" by Ryosuke Kojima?

Tags: identify-this-genre, electronic-music, jazz, similar-artists, piano

What genre does this music belong to: [*Morning Dew* by Ryosuke Kojima](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wqhmiowjBk)?

Recently I heard some music from the anime [W'z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%27z) and I've fallen in love with the music in it. I tried to find most of its music, and ended up with a playlist titled *In Ya Mellow Tone*. I only like some of its tracks and the linked one is one among them.

What I like about this music is the cool jazz and the keyboard, as combined with the beat and the modern production. It would be very cool to know about similar playlists or artists in that category.

Comment: Are you interested in the piano considered by itself, or in the style that includes the electronic production together with the piano sample?

Comment: @ChrisSunami Not interested in piano itself, i like the style in which piano and jazz are mixed, but not a rap or hip hop

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is it's own specific genre, but here are some related ones to help you find more music of this type.

Lo-fi, ambient, and chill-out are all modifiers that can be added to "hip hop" to give more calm and melodic songs --often featuring piano --with modern beats.  From the other side, NuJazz is a jazz offshoot that uses electronic production and beats.

In terms of specific suggestions, here's an album I already know to have some similar sounds (however, with vocals)

Gasoline ["Journey into Abstract Hip Hop"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3q8nGnls1Ow&t=20s)

Here's a track I found searching for ["ambient hip hop piano"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PauC21osmfY).

Here's [a mix for chill out hip hop piano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMLqW056fLs)

Here's [lounge jazz hip hop AKA "lounge hop"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWDnAe9shSA)

Comment: thanks these are very cool, can u suggest some more music without rap, because those are the part i don't like